# 2008 SR2 Server Starts Then Fails to Initialize DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, startup

Got a weird situation going on.

Background: Just transferred Active Directory from a 2003 Server to 2008 SR2. Transferred Global and everything. Removed and disjoined the 2003 server from AD but I have not upgraded Active Directory to 08 only yet. After the transition a problem started. Whenever I reboot the server and I log in, the DNS server is "stopping". After a few minutes it finishes and I can restart it at that point. Once it is restarted, all services come up.

Now I did try to install HyperV (this is a dev server btw). Once the reboot for HyperV, everything was screwed as in I could not ping anything. Uninstalled and had the DNS server issue. Screwed with IPv6 settings (which I am not using) and problem was resolved for a bit. One the problem reappeared I also installed an Intel Pro1000 card and had a bit of success with DNS; then it failed. Weird thing is, outside of an error in syslog stating that the DNS server failed to start, there is no specific error that is generated in either System or DNS Server logs.

Ideas are much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, got it figured out. Had to uninstall and reinstall the network card. Now everything is working properly.

Comment: Weird... glad you got it working.